# If a radio value is ==1 then request ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a registration form that i'm creating. In my html file, I have two radio boxes,

```
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="0" id="whatever" checked//> No
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="1" id="whatever"> Yes
```

If the value is 1 it should send an email using ajax, here is what I have,

```
if($("input[name='whatever']").val()=='2'){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base + 'email',  
        data: vData,
            success: function() {  
              // alert( "I'm the callback")
          } 
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: erm, why do two elements have same id?

Comment: ids should be unique - and are you asking why `if($("input[name='whatever']").val()=='2'){` doesn't trigger as being == '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by fixing your markup so that you don't have duplicate ids:

```
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="0" checked="checked" /> No
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="1" /> Yes
```

and then you could use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to detect the value of the currently selected radio button:

```
if($(':radio[name="whatever"]:checked').val() == '1') {
    // the Yes radio button was checked =>
    // you could do your AJAX request here ...
}
```

or give your radio buttons unique ids:

```
<input id="no" type="radio" name="whatever" value="0" checked="checked" /> No
<input id="yes" type="radio" name="whatever" value="1" /> Yes
```

and then:

```
if($('#yes').is(':checked')) {
    // the Yes radio button was checked =>
    // you could do your AJAX request here ...
}
```